# Non-decreasing log counter in Loki

Tags: prometheus, grafana-loki

I want to count how many bad lines were in the logs. I'm using Loki with recording rules sent to the Prometheus. I want to have a non-decreasing counter for 'bad foo' log line (with all attached labels), with counter going to 0 only if loki was restarted. Is it possible? As far as I understand, `count_over_time` will create a gauge, not a counter. Is it possible to make a counter?

Comment: By `counter_over_time` did mean `count_over_time`?

Comment: Regarding you idea, I don't think it's possible, at least exactly what you described. If you are ok with resets not on Loki restarts, by something like every day/month/year, then it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, it's a typo. I've updated the question. Yes, I'm okay with periodic 'reset to zero', but I want a metric I can use like a normal counter inside prometheus, like `rate`, `increase`, etc.

Comment: First of all, you can use `rate` over usual selector: `rate({filename="mafile.log"} |~ "bad foo" [5m])`. And you can use `count_over_time` instead of `increase`.

Comment: And regarding creation of counter: in Prometheus there are functions like `month()` that combined with logical operand `and` can help to produce something like this. I think that something like this can be repeated in Loki, but first attempts at this failed. I will try a couple more approaches later.

Comment: After a bit more research I hold belief that this cannot be done: Loki supports not all the things present in Prometheus' functions, and functions related to time are one of those unsupported features.

Comment: Thank you. Seems that rate is a single available option.